# IOS - Selecting a compound array and passing it to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, storyboard

I have an array of objects. I want to select a subgroup of those and pass that to detailView.

I'm stuck between using didSelectRowAtIndexPath, or prepareForSegue

This is my mainVC code for didSelect:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    tempArray = [mainArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    NSString *numberString = [tempArray valueForKey:@"number"];


    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"number =[c] %@",numberString];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setIncludesSubentities:NO];
     NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    selectedObjects = [array mutableCopy];
   NSLog(@"selectedObjects: %@", selectedObjects); << -- this looks ok

    detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
    detailsViewController.selectedObjects = selectedObjects;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainToDetails" sender:self.view];
}
```

In this example, selectedObjects shows fine. When I get to the detailView, selectedObjects is null.

```
NSIndexPath *path = [mainTable indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    tempArray = [main objectAtIndex: path]; << this isn't right.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nil because you created an instance of your controller with alloc init that never appears on screen. Since you're using segues, the segue creates the new instance, and you should pass the data in prepareForSegue where you can get a reference to this controller with segue.destinationViewController.

Comment: I've looked everywhere, (must be missing it), how do I find my array when in prepareForSegue. There is no link to an indexPath.row. I get this:  Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSIndexPath *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long').

Comment: @DavidDelMonte, connect the segue from the cell to the next controller, and then the sender argument in prepareForSegue:sender: will be the cell. You can get the indexPath from the cell with the table view method indexPathForCell. Move all the code you have in didSelectRowAtIndexPath into prepareForSegue (but don't call performSegueWithIdentifier: since the segue will be called by selecting the cell).

Comment: thank you Sir. I followed your suggestion. Worked fine.. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath the replace this line

```
detailsViewController = [[DetailsViewController alloc] init];
```

with below line

```
detailsViewController = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR STORYBOARD_ID"];
detailsViewController.selectedObjects = selectedObjects;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. I ended up going with the prepareForSegue method. I do appreciate your help. +1